# How to speed up the performance of array masking from the results of numpy.searchsorted in python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to generate a mask from the results of numpy.searchsorted():

```
import numpy as np

# generate test examples
x = np.random.rand(1000000)
y = np.random.rand(200)

# sort x
idx = np.argsort(x)
sorted_x = np.take_along_axis(x, idx, axis=-1)

# searchsort y in x
pt = np.searchsorted(sorted_x, y)
```

`pt` is an array. Then I want to create a boolean mask of size `(200, 1000000)` with True values when its indices are `idx[0:pt[i]]`, and I come up with a for-loop like this:

```
mask = np.zeros((200, 1000000), dtype='bool')
for i in range(200):
     mask[i, idx[0:pt[i]]] = True
```

Anyone has an idea to speed up the for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Approach #1

Going by the new-found information picked up off [`OP's comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497080/how-to-speed-up-the-performance-of-array-masking-from-the-results-of-numpy-searc#comment114234824_64599339) that states only `y` is changing in real-time, we can pre-process lots of stuffs around `x` and hence do much better. We will create a hashing array that will store stepped masks. For the part that involves `y`, we will simply index into the hashing array with the indices obtained off `searchsorted`  which will approximate the final mask array. A final step of assigning the remaining bools could be offloaded to numba given its ragged nature. This should also be beneficial if we decide to scale up the lengths of `y`.

Let's look at the implementation.

**Pre-processing with `x` :**

```
sidx = x.argsort()
ssidx = x.argsort().argsort()

# Choose a scale factor. 
# 1. A small one would store more mapping info, hence faster but occupy more mem
# 2. A big one would store less mapping info, hence slower, but memory efficient.
scale_factor = 100
mapar = np.arange(0,len(x),scale_factor)[:,None] > ssidx
```

**Remaining steps with `y` :**

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def array_masking3(out, starts, idx, sidx):
    N = len(out)
    for i in nb.prange(N):
        for j in nb.prange(starts[i], idx[i]):
            out[i,sidx[j]] = True
    return out

idx = np.searchsorted(x,y,sorter=sidx)
s0 = idx//scale_factor
starts = s0*scale_factor
out = mapar[s0]
out = array_masking3(out, starts, idx, sidx)
```

**Benchmarking**

```
In [2]: x = np.random.rand(1000000)
   ...: y = np.random.rand(200)

In [3]: ## Pre-processing step with "x"
   ...: sidx = x.argsort()
   ...: ssidx = x.argsort().argsort()
   ...: scale_factor = 100
   ...: mapar = np.arange(0,len(x),scale_factor)[:,None] > ssidx

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: idx = np.searchsorted(x,y,sorter=sidx)
   ...: s0 = idx//scale_factor
   ...: starts = s0*scale_factor
   ...: out = mapar[s0]
   ...: out = array_masking3(out, starts, idx, sidx)
41 ms ± 141 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

 # A 1/10th smaller hashing array has similar timings
In [7]: scale_factor = 1000
   ...: mapar = np.arange(0,len(x),scale_factor)[:,None] > ssidx

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: idx = np.searchsorted(x,y,sorter=sidx)
   ...: s0 = idx//scale_factor
   ...: starts = s0*scale_factor
   ...: out = mapar[s0]
   ...: out = array_masking3(out, starts, idx, sidx)
40.6 ms ± 196 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# @silgon's soln    
In [5]: %timeit x[np.newaxis,:] < y[:,np.newaxis]
138 ms ± 896 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

#### Approach #2

This borrowed a good part from [`OP's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64534208/).

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def array_masking2(mask1D, mask_out, idx, pt):
    n = len(idx)
    for j in nb.prange(len(pt)):
        if mask1D[j]:
            for i in nb.prange(pt[j],n):
                mask_out[j, idx[i]] = False
        else:
            for i in nb.prange(pt[j]):
                mask_out[j, idx[i]] = True
    return mask_out

def app2(idx, pt):
    m,n = len(pt), len(idx)      
    mask1 = pt>len(x)//2
    mask2 = np.broadcast_to(mask1[:,None], (m,n)).copy()
    return array_masking2(mask1, mask2, idx, pt)
```

So, the idea is once, we have larger than half of indices to be set `True`, we switch over to set `False` instead after pre-assigning those rows as all `True`. This results in lesser memory accesses and hence some noticeable performance boost.

#### Benchmarking

OP's solution :

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def array_masking(mask, idx, pt):
    for j in nb.prange(pt.shape[0]):
        for i in nb.prange(pt[j]):
            mask[j, idx[i]] = True
    return mask

def app1(idx, pt):
    m,n = len(pt), len(idx)      
    mask = np.zeros((m, n), dtype='bool')
    return array_masking(mask, idx, pt)
```

Timings -

```
In [5]: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: x = np.random.rand(1000000)
   ...: y = np.random.rand(200)

In [6]: %timeit app1(idx, pt)
264 ms ± 8.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit app2(idx, pt)
165 ms ± 3.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a boost on the performance. Your code runs 30% faster than my previous one on my computer.

Comment: @f.c. Would approach #1 be a viable solution for you? Can you give us some feedback on the solution(s) you are leaning towards for the bounty? Could be helpful if the answers could be improved, if need be.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tested your approach #1. You are the winner so far. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have increase the `scale_factor` to `2000` because of memory issue, and the speedup is about 2.5x on my computer, which is super.

Comment: @f.c. Awesome! Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternate answer but not sure that it's exactly what you need.

```py
x = np.random.rand(1000000)
y = np.random.rand(200)
mask = x[np.newaxis,:] < y[:,np.newaxis]
```

Note: I mentioned that maybe it's not what you need because you specify the need of `numpy.searchsorted()` and here I don't use it, however I get the same result. It might also be useful to somebody else in some future if it doesn't completely fits your needs ;).

**Timings (@DanielF edit)**

Setup:

```
import numpy as np

# generate test examples
x = np.random.rand(1000000)
y = np.random.rand(200)

# sort x
idx = np.argsort(x)
sorted_x = np.take_along_axis(x, idx, axis=-1)
```

Running:

```
%%timeit   #  silgon
mask = x[np.newaxis,:] < y[:,np.newaxis]

166 ms ± 3.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit    # Divakar
pt = np.searchsorted(sorted_x, y)
mask = app2(idx, pt)

316 ms ± 29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%%timeit   #  f.c.
pt = np.searchsorted(sorted_x, y)
mask = np.zeros((200, 1000000), dtype='bool')
for i in range(200):
     mask[i, idx[0:pt[i]]] = True
     
466 ms ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: You are right. It is the brute-force search version which gives the same results. The reason to use numpy.searchsorted is to speed up the computation.

Comment: @f.c. does `np.searchsorted` really speed up computation compared to this?

Comment: @DanielF Good question, and yes. It saves 70% of the time on my computer.

Comment: @f.c. I cannot add an image in the comments. I did a quick test compared to @Divakar function ([https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6QOk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6QOk.png)). I also included the `argsort`, `take_long_axis` and `search_sorted` to compare that both functions do the same thing (since mine is a one liner). I might get the time to do some proper benchmark later.

Comment: @silgon Thanks. Please keep in mind that I only care about the performance of the `np.searchsorted` and `mask`. In my case, `argsort` and `take_long_axis` can be calculated in advance. Only the `y` is changing in real time.

Comment: In my opinion, the bottleneck is the masking, that is `mask[i, idx[0:pt[i]]] = True` in my question. The complexity of np.searchsorted is O(log(n)) which is already super fast.

Comment: I see, in that case, what you imply is correct. I get `131 ms` with only `np.searchsorted` and @Divakar 's function, while mine which did the comparison too was `169 ms`. Good luck and cheers! =)

Comment: I honestly don't see the time benefit on my system.  I see the above as twice as fast as Divakar's and three times as fast as the original.

Comment: Edited the answer with my timings.

Comment: @Daniel @silgon I want to point out one thing, that is using `np.searchsorted` is in fact much faster than @silgon 's brute force method. The reason that you got short timings is when you run the numba code `app2`, python takes a long time (in the first run) to compile the code. And `%%timeit` takes into account the compile time in your case. If you run the numba code once before timing it, you will end up with different results of timings.

Comment: I did already run to compile it before that.  Before that it was ~800ms

Comment: It doesn't really matter, since apparently @Divakar's works faster on your machine.  Great!  Maybe I just have some weird architecture difference

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a numba version of the for-loop, and it is slightly faster than the python version. Here is the code:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def array_masking(mask, idx, pt):
    for j in nb.prange(pt.shape[0]):
        for i in nb.prange(pt[j]):
            mask[j, idx[i]] = True
```

I am looking for further speedup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For a better clarity, you're looking for a fast way to determine mask of indices of items of `x` that are smaller than `y[i]`. For example, if indices that sorts items of `x` are:

```
np.argsort(x) = [5, 0, 2, 10, 7, 8, 9, 11, 1, 6, 3, 4]
```

and you know that `8` items are smaller than `y[i]`, you'll need to choose first 8 items from inverse order of that list then:

```
arg_inv = [1, 8, 2, 10, 11, 0, 9, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7]
```

The easiest approach of this problem is advanced indexing:

```
length_x, length_y = len(x), len(y)
idx = np.argsort(x)
arg_inv = np.argsort(idx)
pt = np.searchsorted(x, y, sorter=idx)
mask = np.zeros((length_y, length_x), dtype='bool')
row, col = np.divmod(np.arange(length_x * length_y), length_x)
mask[row, col] = arg_inv[col] < pt[row]
return mask
```

I also add an example of small samples:

```
x = [0.809 0.958 0.881 0.146 0.882 0.421 0.604]
y = [0.119 0.981 0.775 0.254]
np.sort(x) = [0.146 0.421 0.604 0.809 0.881 0.882 0.958]
np.argsort(x) = [3 5 6 0 2 4 1]
arg_inv = [3 6 4 0 5 1 2]
pt = [0 7 3 1]
Process of advanced indexing:

    row  col  arg_inv[col]  pt[row]  arg_inv[col] < pt[row]
0     0    0             3        0                       0
1     0    1             6        0                       0
2     0    2             4        0                       0
3     0    3             0        0                       0
4     0    4             5        0                       0
5     0    5             1        0                       0
6     0    6             2        0                       0
7     1    0             3        7                       1
8     1    1             6        7                       1
9     1    2             4        7                       1
10    1    3             0        7                       1
11    1    4             5        7                       1
12    1    5             1        7                       1
13    1    6             2        7                       1
14    2    0             3        3                       0
15    2    1             6        3                       0
16    2    2             4        3                       0
17    2    3             0        3                       1
18    2    4             5        3                       0
19    2    5             1        3                       1
20    2    6             2        3                       1
21    3    0             3        1                       0
22    3    1             6        1                       0
23    3    2             4        1                       0
24    3    3             0        1                       1
25    3    4             5        1                       0
26    3    5             1        1                       0
27    3    6             2        1                       0
```

Comment: It seems it does not work if x has repeated elements, for example x = np.array([0.1  0.3  0.2  0.25  0.2  0.25])

Comment: @f.c. Thanks for response. I assumed this is impossible with `np.random.rand` call. I'll fix this later, meanwhile, might `arg_inv = np.argsort(np.argsort(x))` instead of `np.unique` help?

Comment: I use `np.random.rand` to generate the test data. In practice, `x` does have repeated values. Thanks.

Comment: I think np.argsort(np.argsort(x)) should work. I will test the performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, your masking is 7x slower than the for-loop and consumes 4x more memory. I would keep the for-loop. But thanks for trying.

Comment: @f.c. I guess that for-loop is not a bottleneck if amount of iterations is small.